# Prevent calling angular factory every time template is loaded

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and Angular Routing. I have template 'home.html' and controller for that template 'homeController'. Also, I have this factory:

```
app.factory('therapyService', function ($http) {
  return {
    getTherapies: function () {
      //return the promise directly.
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/application/api/rest/therapy').then(function (result) {
        //resolve the promise as the data
        return result.data;
      });
    }
  }
});

In controller:
therapyService.getTherapies().then(function (results) {
$scope.therapies = results;
...
}
```

Problem is whenever I click on that page, that http call is called all over again. I want it called only first time when page is loaded first time. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable caching for individual calls by passing a configuration argument to the `$http` call:

```
return $http.get('url', { cache: true }).then(...)
```

---

If you see that most of your calls need to be cached and very few uncached, then you can enable the caching by default for your calls during the configuration phase of your application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
      .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
           $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
      }])
```

Then you can explicitly disable caching for some calls by passing `{ cache: false }`. I would recommend explicitly enabling caching. Caching is an optimization and enabling it by default can risk breaking the application if you forget to disable it at some point.

Comment: @firstChild The caching lasts for the application's lifetime.